# Add Space Programmatically At The Bottom Of A UIView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Believe me or not, I have spent almost 2 hours now figuring out how to put my button under a `UIView` with a constant space of something like 15 points.

First, check my code. I have been using .center property for aligning my elements/objects. The 'utc' is a `UIView` with no background color. The two textfields are subviews of utc `UIView`.

The views here seems perfectly fine positioned, but I need to know how to use constraints instead. Again, just a constant (like 15) space above the loginButton (so below utc `UIView`).

Please, if you're going to down vote my honest question, explain as well. The app is for the Portrait Position of iPhones only.

[image]

Here is my complete code for putting the elements:

```
// reference
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

CGSize miniButtonWidth = CGSizeMake(screenWidth * 0.47f, 50);
// add UI View For TextFields
UIView *utc = [[UIView alloc] init];
// utc.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
utc.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth * 0.95, 100);
utc.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth * 0.50, screenHeight * 0.60);
[utc setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:utc];

// add textfield1
UITextField *emailTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, utc.frame.size.width, miniButtonWidth.height)];
//emailTextField.center = CGPointMake(utc.frame.size.width * 0.5, utc.frame.size.height * 0.01);
emailTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
emailTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textfieldLogIn.png"];
emailTextField.placeholder = @" Email Address";
emailTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[utc addSubview:emailTextField];

// add divider
UIImageView *divider = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth * 0.97, 10)];
divider.center = CGPointMake(utc.frame.size.width * 0.5, utc.frame.size.height * 0.50);
divider.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dividerLogIn.png"];
divider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
divider.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[utc addSubview: divider];

// add textfield2
UITextField *passwordTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, utc.frame.size.width, miniButtonWidth.height)];
passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
passwordTextField.center = CGPointMake(utc.frame.size.width * 0.5, utc.frame.size.height * 0.75);
passwordTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
passwordTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textfieldLogIn.png"];
passwordTextField.placeholder = @" Password";
passwordTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[utc addSubview:passwordTextField];


// add button for Forgot?
UIButton *forgotBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
forgotBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth * 0.97, miniButtonWidth.height);
forgotBtn.center = CGPointMake(passwordTextField.frame.size.width * 0.85, passwordTextField.frame.size.height * 0.50);
[forgotBtn setTitle:@"Forgot?" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[forgotBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(forgotBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[passwordTextField addSubview: forgotBtn];

// add button login
UIButton *loginBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
loginBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, utc.frame.size.width, miniButtonWidth.height);
loginBtn.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth * 0.50, (screenHeight * 0.60) + 10);
[loginBtn setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[loginBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(loginBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[loginBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signinupLogIn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginBtn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[loginBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"signindownLogIn.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.view addSubview: loginBtn];
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using auto constraints?

Comment: Couldn't u just use another container for utc + login-button and add this container to self.view? In this container you just set the frames correctly, without setting center, and then add it to self.view with container.center set appropriate.

Comment: what is the value of "miniButtonWidth.height"?

Comment: value of "screenWidth"?

Comment: Hello all, I have added the miniButton code and stuffs. I don't know auto constraints. About adding another container, I'm just really interested in adding a space approach. I have also tried adding constraints but the other views become misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to learn about Auto-Layout. Once you know how to use Auto-Layout's constraints, you'll get your problem solved.

**What is Auto-Layout?**

With four different iPhone's screen sizes now, it makes no sense to position the views using the old ways (setting frame, center, etc.). And here Auto-Layout comes to solve this problem. Basically, instead of directly setting the view's frame, you set some constraints to *describe* how the view should be positioned regardless of the screen size (e.g. in the middle of the screen, aligned with some other view, etc.).

**Some simple resources to begin with:**

1. [The always great Ray Wenderlich's tutorial (Two parts).](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)
2. [App Coda's tutorial.](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/)

Hope it helps.